# Trying to calculate rate of change from imported excel column with first and last value

Tags: python

```
import xlrd

loc = ("/Users/chrissmith/Desktop/final/HistoricalData.xls")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
```

So this code imports an excel column. Im looking for something that takes the first value at the top of the column and the last value all the way of the bottom of the column and calculates the rate of change between the two values

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

loc = ("/Users/chrissmith/Desktop/final/HistoricalData.xls")

xl = pd.read_excel(loc)

#enter column name to get data of the column 
column = xl["column name"]
lenght = len(column)

change = column[0]-column[lenght-1]

#to find rate of change
rate_of_change = change/lenght

print(rate_of_change)
```